# Git Flow Init Command not recognized - command not found

Tags: windows, git, git-bash, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

I inherited a workstation that a previous developer at my company used. IT did not wipe + reprovision the laptop before I started and I believe this may be why I'm seeing these issues.

I'm trying to run the git flow commands from my ConEmu terminal. It seems like git-flow is installed and recognized, but every time I try to run a gitflow command, I get a printout like this

```
git flow init
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]showcommands) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]force) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]defaults) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]local) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]global) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]system) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]file) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]feature) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]bugfix) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]release) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]hotfix) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]support) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]tag) already exists
C:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/gitflow-shFlags: line 398: tr: command not found
flags:WARN definition for ([no]help!) already exists
flags:FATAL unrecognized option (,)
```

I've tried installing the latest version of git for windows to see if that would 'repair' the gitflow installation

I've tried other terminal emulators, like windows cmd and gitbash.

As a workaround, I had to log into one of our sandbox servers, install git for windows, and run the git flow commands there.

Answer (score 1):

try to re-install git flow, it worked for me.

```
brew unlink git-flow-avh
brew reinstall git-flow
```

Comment: Is that means change to original git-flow from git-flow-avh?